# custom theme cannot be applied in button

Tags: android, button, themes

This is my custom style:

```
<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#00c4a9</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/user_button_size</item>
</style>
```

This is my button layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_exchange"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin_16"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/integral_exchange_goods" />
```

This is the result:[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWG4l.png)

but the theme cannot be applied in the button. Why?
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
style="@style/ButtonTheme"
```

Comment: the attribute colorButtonNormal cannot be applied if use style

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your Activity extends AppCompatActivity and use appcompat theme

Answer (score 0):

The below link describes why theme is not applied to button.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191980

Also refer the below for adding custom theme for button:
http://manuel-ohlendorf.de/blog/2015/09/03/material-design-buttons-with-appcompat/

Answer (score 0):

Change your styles parent from,

```
parent="android:Widget.Button"
```

to,

```
parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button"
```

Also make sure you use an `AppCompat` theme.